# Task scheduler with one exception per year

Tags: scheduled-task

Currently, we have tasks with Windows Task Scheduler that run each night. The tasks pump data from one database to another. Data is also transformed in this process. It is not a one to one copy. The date interval is one month back in time. All this works fine.

But now a new requirement arrives. Once per year we should pump data one year back in time. Preferbly on a Sunday but I saw that Task Scheduler can fix that.

But it is double work as normal nightly pumping also happens. How can I avoid this as the pumping is a demanding process ? The datapump is inhouse software so we have complete control of it.

So it would be great if I could make a normal schedule with a list of exception dates to stop the trigger.

Comment: The software should probably just do this itself. It's the best place for this sort of business logic anyway.

Comment: As @MichaelHampton suggests, perhaps the datapump should check for the date and perform differently on that one day.

Comment: We found another solution to this. We simply schedule them to not occur at same time